# (offline) validation for a SSL Connection

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

Lets asume you have a webclient that can only connect to one endpoint, a HTTPS webserver. The certificate that is used, is always from a certificate authority (CA).

My motivation is to assure that the used certificate is issused from a trustet party. 
Because the software should be running without an update and handle new certificates, certificate pinning is not an option.

In C# you can use a callback to use our own validation

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback
```

I get the used X509Certificate and the X509Chain.

```
// Summary:
//     Verifies the remote Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) certificate used for authentication.
//
// Parameters:
//   sender:
//     An object that contains state information for this validation.
//
//   certificate:
//     The certificate used to authenticate the remote party.
//
//   chain:
//     The chain of certificate authorities associated with the remote certificate.
//
//   sslPolicyErrors:
//     One or more errors associated with the remote certificate.
//
// Returns:
//     A System.Boolean value that determines whether the specified certificate
//     is accepted for authentication.
public delegate bool RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors);
```

**My idea** is to enroll the software with a list of a common CAs Root certificate fingerprints. 
And then test the X509Chain

- that one certificate has the same fingerprint (as a common CAs Root certificate)
- that the chain from this CAs Root certificate to the issued certificate is vaid
- that the certificate is valid in time (ignore revoaktion, because

**My Questions**

- Has anyone a better idea?
- How to proof that the chain is valid?

Answer (score 0):

> ... with a list of a common CAs Root certificate fingerprints.
>
> ...that the chain from this CAs Root certificate to the issued certificate is vaid

You can check that certificate matches a fingerprint, but you can not verify the relationship between certificates (the chain) by fingerprints alone. Verification of the chain is done by verifying the signature on the certificate and to do this you need the signers public key which is contained in the signers certificate.

Apart from that I would assume that C# has the necessary methods to verify a certificate chain against your own set of trusted CA, so you don't need to add your own verification callback.